# How do I resolve this Selenium exception on a Mac thats says "chrome not reachable"?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to learn how to automate web processes using Selenium and hopefully be able to build robust web scrapers and stuff. So, I just finished installing Pycharm and Selenium, and I am just trying to run a simple snippet of code that opens a web page in chrome, nothing too fancy. My code is as follows (it's in Python of course)

```
from selenium import webdriver


PATH = "/Users/Kudzie/Tools/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://orbitrevolution.tech')
```

So , when I run this code, I get this exception, and I have no idea how to solve this, I've tried reading past variations of this question but i didn't seem to get a solution that works. the exception is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kudzie/PycharmProjects/Web Scraper/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
  File "/Users/Kudzie/PycharmProjects/Web Scraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Users/Kudzie/PycharmProjects/Web Scraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/Kudzie/PycharmProjects/Web Scraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/Kudzie/PycharmProjects/Web Scraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/Kudzie/PycharmProjects/Web Scraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

With this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
```

Comment: I tried that and i now have a different error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`

Comment: Hmmm, not sure on that one.  That probably requires a new question so this doesn't get lost in the mix, I know the piece I gave you is needed but it sounds like something else is going on as well.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for taking your time to respond